# Certain Session Variables are not carrying over

Tags: php, arrays, session, set

I am currently coding a project in which requires the user to login to the website before being able to view any information. I am currently tracking when a user is logged in or not by using a Session Variable named "usernamelogged". I believe I have all my formatting correct as well.
After logging in you're brought to the main page, in which I have set up (temporarily) to print_r() the session array. Im also using a class to help prevent session hijacking.

**Login Page Relevant PHP:**

```
<?php
include dirname(__FILE__).'/includes.php';//INCLUDES FILE
if ($count == 1) {// IF USERNAME AND PASSWORD ARE GOOD
    SessionManager::sessionStart('LoginDetails', 10800, '/', 'localhost', true, $username);
    $_SESSION['usernamelogged'] = $username;//Declare Session
header("location: members.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}

?>
```

**Here** is where the problem occurs. Down below I have it print_r() the array, in which comes up with the following details:

> Array ( [IPaddress] => *Censored IP* [userAgent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36 )

**However** you will notice that there is no "usernamelogged" in that array like there should be.
Here is the php from the page you receive after logging in:

```
<?php
include dirname(__FILE__).'/includes.php';
SessionManager::sessionStart('LoginDetails', 0, '/', 'localhost', true, $_SESSION['usernamelogged']);
print_r ($_SESSION);// TEMP
echo $_SESSION['usernamelogged'];
$checkses = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE username=:user");
$checkses->bindParam(':user', $_SESSION['usernamelogged']);
$checkses->execute();
$count = $checkses->rowCount();
if (!$count == 1) {
    echo "Error, you're not logged in";
    print_r($count);//TEMP
    //header("location: login.php");
    die();
}
include dirname(__FILE__).'/header.php';
 ?>
```

**Finally, the class I am using for session hijacking:**

```
class SessionManager
{
   static function sessionStart($name, $limit = 0, $path = '/', $domain = null, $secure = null, $username)
{
    // Set the cookie name
    session_name($name . '_Session');

    // Set SSL level
    $https = isset($secure) ? $secure : isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']);

    // Set session cookie options
    session_set_cookie_params($limit, $path, $domain, $https, true);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usernamelogged'] = $username;

    // Make sure the session hasn't expired, and destroy it if it has
    if(self::validateSession())
    {
        // Check to see if the session is new or a hijacking attempt
        if(!self::preventHijacking())
        {
            // Reset session data and regenerate id
            $_SESSION = array();
            $_SESSION['IPaddress'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $_SESSION['userAgent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            self::regenerateSession();

        // Give a 5% chance of the session id changing on any request
        }elseif(rand(1, 100) <= 5){
            self::regenerateSession();
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
    }
}
   static protected function preventHijacking()
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['IPaddress']) || !isset($_SESSION['userAgent']))
        return false;

    if ($_SESSION['IPaddress'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        return false;

    if( $_SESSION['userAgent'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
        return false;

    return true;
}
static function regenerateSession()
{
    // If this session is obsolete it means there already is a new id
    if(isset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE'])){
        if($_SESSION['OBSOLETE'] == true){
        return; 
        }
    }

    // Set current session to expire in 10 seconds
    $_SESSION['OBSOLETE'] = true;
    $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] = time() + 10;

    // Create new session without destroying the old one
    session_regenerate_id(false);

    // Grab current session ID and close both sessions to allow other scripts to use them
    $newSession = session_id();
    session_write_close();

    // Set session ID to the new one, and start it back up again
    session_id($newSession);
    session_start();

    // Now we unset the obsolete and expiration values for the session we want to keep
    unset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']);
    unset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']);
}
static protected function validateSession()
{
    if( isset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']) && !isset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']) )
        return false;

    if(isset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']) && $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] < time())
        return false;

    return true;
}
}
```

**Other Details:**

- I cut out the HTML and CSS and only gave the PHP.
- I don't have any form of output before my session_start();
- **PHP Version 5.4.40** and **Apache 2.4.12**

There are no more details that I can think of.

Im happy to answer any questions I can, **THANKS for reading and helping!**

**Edit:**

As requested,
The print out of $_SERVER:

```
Array ( [UNIQUE_ID] => VWvIW2uWJsoAACKtzW8AAAAC [HTTPS] => on [SSL_TLS_SNI] => *Censored* [HTTP_HOST] => *Censored* [HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-Alive [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip [HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY] => US [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => *CENSORED* [HTTP_CF_RAY] => 1ef79bdf5d900418-ORD [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => https [HTTP_CF_VISITOR] => {"scheme":"https"} [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36 [HTTP_DNT] => 1 [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6 [HTTP_COOKIE] => __cfduid=d616d6faa0ec4dd338e855665846ad2da1432945387 [HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP] => *CENSORED* [PATH] => /bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin [LD_LIBRARY_PATH] => /usr/local/apache/lib [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.4.40 [SERVER_NAME] => bbwatch.co.uk [SERVER_ADDR] => *CENSORED* [SERVER_PORT] => 443 [REMOTE_ADDR] => *CENSORED* [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/bbwatchc/public_html [REQUEST_SCHEME] => https [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/bbwatchc/public_html [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@*Censored* [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/***/public_html/members.php [REMOTE_PORT] => 35348 [REMOTE_USER] => *CENSORED* [AUTH_TYPE] => Basic [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1 [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1 [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET [QUERY_STRING] => [REQUEST_URI] => /members.php [SCRIPT_NAME] => /members.php [PHP_SELF] => /members.php [PHP_AUTH_USER] => *CENSORED* [PHP_AUTH_PW] => *CENSORED* [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1433127003.37 [REQUEST_TIME] => 1433127003 [argv] => Array ( ) [argc] => 0 )
```

Also, the printout of $_SESSION:

```
Array ( [IPaddress] => *CENSORED* [userAgent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36 ) Error, you're not logged in0
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` is being wiped when `if(!self::preventHijacking())` is `true` - could you check if your script is always going that way?

Comment: @PeterTutervai Yes, every time the class runs, it is triggering the preventHijacking `IF` section.

Comment: Then please check what is going wrong in `preventHijacking`, as that shouldn't be returning `false` in every run. Could you print out the contents of `$_SESSION` in `preventHijacking` and the contents of `$_SERVER` ?

Comment: @PeterTutervai | I have added those to the main post